# System-wide command to backup specific directory

Tags: shortcut-keys, backup

After overwriting some code I worked a while on only just before I went to back everything up, I'm looking for a what to get into a habit of backing up entire directories with just a keyboard shortcut just like the instinctive <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> one presses every 30 seconds when working on something painstaking.

Example: Working on a project with directories and sub-directories and press the keyboard command to back it up to a separate location (either a separate partition on the same disk or an entirely different disk).

Finally, both

```sh
sh -c 'rsync -azh home/username/Documents home/username/Doc_Backup'
```

and

```sh
sh -c 'rsync -azh ~/Documents ~/Doc_Backup'
```

worked for me (*Settings* → *Keyboard* → <kbd>+</kbd>).

Ultimately, I wrote a shell script to copy several directories and finally recursively zip them:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
rsync -azh '/home/user_name/Documents/ex1'
rsync -azh '/home/user_name/Documents/ex2'
zip -r '/home/user_name/Doc_Backup/Backup.zip' '/home/user_name/Doc_Backup/Backup'
rm -rf '/home/user_name/Doc_Backup/Backup'
```

Comment: Might I suggest an editor that allows multiple undo / redo levels. Also the same editor that can keep backups of the same file through multiple generations of edits / saves. Also automated daily, weekly, monthly and yearly backup cycles because sometimes you don't realize a source file has been deleted, copied over or corrupted until much later.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sure. I'm using Spyder although the issue was that I misclicked when I made an `__init__.py` and overwrote a module because it brilliantly replaces the filename I misclicked on into the field for naming my new file. I already had an `__init__.py` so when it prompted me about replacing a file I clicked okay... then I realized what happened and my original was overwritten

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by creating a custom hotkey.

Open `Control Center`, click on `Keyboard`, then click `shortcuts` tab. Click `add shortcut`. Enter a name such as "Backup work". Then, for the command, enter:

```
sh -c 'rsync -azh ~/my/work/folder /path/to/backup/folder'
```

Click add, then click on new shortcut to add the key combination to activate it. Chose a combination that is not used by your program or the system. Note: some desktops may have you add the key combination before adding the shortcut.

#### Explanation of command

`rsync` is a file synchronizer software. The first execute may take some time as it has to copy all the files. But during subsequent runs, it looks for changes and copies the changes.

- `-a` creates a recursive (copies subdirectories) archive that preserves owner, permissions and timestamp.
- `-z` compresses file data for sending.
- `-h` prints numbers in a human readable format.

Thus, this command will copy files and sub-folders from `/my/work/folder` to `/path/to/backup/folder`; preserving ownership, permissions, and timestamps; and compresses file data.

NOTE: I assumed the work folder is in your home directory thus the addition of `~`. If it isn't in your home folder, then provide the absolute path to the work folder.

Comment: This is definitely what I'm looking for except I've had a little trouble setting it up. Since I'm reformatting a drive I just tried on the same disk to do the backup. I tried to backup `/home/Documents` just to `/home/username/Doc_Backup`. I made the shortcut something long and unlikely to be mistakenly pressed: `shift+ctrl+alt+s`. The new shortcut appears in the menu but upon pressing it it does nothing

Comment: there is no `/home/Documents` .... it is `/home/username/Documents`  also `~/Documents` should work.

Comment: I just tested myself ...  did you put single quotes around the command?  `'rsync -avh ~/Documents ~/Doc_Backup'`  should work for you.

Comment: Oops I tried to be more explicit with the `home` but in the command it had `~`. I've added a screenshot of the command as it stands on my computer to my question. I'll note that I am using Budgie but I fail to see why that'd make a difference at this point.

Comment: In the terminal, it claims `No such file or directory` yet it does and i can `cd` into it

Comment: @CircArgs in all likelihood, the shortcut command executor does not use a shell to run commands; so things like `~` don't get expanded. Try: `sh -c 'rsync -azh ~/Documents ~/Doc_Backup'`

Comment: @muru Thanks! I didn't take your command directly (it worked in the terminal but not with the shortcut. I did not put single quotes around what you posted so idk if that was a problem. However, i expanded out the `~` and that worked (no compression though but Ill take it as I never actually asked for it).

Comment: @muru nvm yours works as the shortcut too. Just no zip (maybe because it's a directory and not a single file?). Thanks again

Comment: @CircArgs if you're talking about the `-z` option, it compresses data will sending it to the target (so data is read from source, compressed, send to target, decompressed). If you want to compress the backup itself, maybe create tarballs of it.

Comment: @muru got it. Just wrote a shell script and added zipping at the end.