New keyboard shortcut similar to the one for Unicode
I use Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland.
How can I define a new shortcut that behaves similarly to Ctrl+Shift+U for entering Unicode characters?
I would like to set up a new shortcut for entering LaTeX commands which will then be translated into Unicode characters using unicodeit.  For instance, if I enter
Ctrl+Shift+T followed by \subseteq
in a text editor or the terminal, I would like the system to run
python3 -m unicodeit.cli \\subseteq
so that I get ⊆.
An alternative possibility I would be happy with is to get ⊆ if I write \subseteq, highlight it, and then press Ctrl+Shift+T.
Is this possible without low-level programming?

Pls, search first before writing a question, it probably is answered https://askubuntu.com/questions/963471/system-wide-command-to-backup-specific-directory/963475?r=SearchResults&s=17%7C25.1639#963475

@amar: How is your link answering my question?

If you're fine with:

Hitting Ctrl+Shift+T
Entering the LaTeX command (e.g. \subseteq) in a textbox
Hitting Ctrl+V (or Ctrl+Shift+V if in a terminal)1

Then you can create a custom keyboard shortcut that will automate the task.
The shortcut relies on zenity and xclip: zenity should be installed by default, while xclip should not: sudo apt install xclip.
To create the shortcut: open "Settings" and navigate to "Keyboard" -> "View and Customize Shortcuts" -> "Custom Shortcuts";
Then, create a new shortcut and bind it to Ctrl+Shift+T.
The shortcut should run this command:
sh -c 'zenity --entry --title=unicodeit --text= | xargs -0 python3 -m unicodeit.cli | tr -d "\n" | xclip -sel clip'

Which will:

Show a popup named "unicodeit" containing a textbox, a "Cancel" button and an "OK" button;
Take whatever has been inputted into the textbox, append a newline to it and pass it as an argument to python3 -m unicodeit.cli, using xargs -0 so that a single argument will be passed to python3 -m unicodeit.cli and so that quotes, backslashes and whitespace will be interpreted literally (unicodeit will seamlessly deal with the trailing newline)
Remove the trailing newlines from the output of python3 -m unicodeit.cli and copy it into the clipboard, ready to be pasted using Ctrl+V (or Ctrl+Shift+V if in a terminal)


1: I wanted to automate this step as well, but currently I'm not able to; xdotool won't work on Wayland, and the ydotool version I have installed crashes no matter what arguments / inputs I feed to it (perhaps a bug?) - I'll try and update this once I've managed to fix the issue with ydotool

Awesome!  This is already much better than having to copy-paste from a web browser!  In fact, opening a textbox might be better than what I originally had in mind because it allows for longer LaTeX expressions than a single command.

Currently, I have to duplicate the backslashes (i.e., write \alpha\beta instead of \alpha\beta).  Can this be fixed?

I never managed to run ydotool without sudo.

@Algernon Try sh -c 'zenity --entry --title=unicodeit --text= | tr -d '\n' | xargs -0 python3 -m unicodeit.cli | xclip -sel clip', I added -0 to xargs, which should take care of quoting / escaping when needed (which will also take care of spaces in the command), and a tr command before xargs to get rid of the trailing newline from zenith (which in combination with xargs -0 would otherwise persist in the buffer). Does the Python script also add a newline at the end? If so, do you need it?

@Algernon I can't test this with unicodeit so please let me know if it works ok with slashes and spaces. About the ydotool thing, perhaps you're right. I'll try to figure out a way, it's a shame just that one last bit is preventing this from being even more useful.

The new version in the comments fixed the problem of needing double backslashsed.  It also takes care of quotation marks (I hadn't noticed this issue before).  There are now two newlines at the end.  Your original code added only one newline.  The Python script doesn't add a newline at the end.  It is preferable to have none.

@Algernon Ah I goofed, I should've double-quoted the tr command: however it appears as though unicodeit wold seamlessly deal with a newline at the end of the argument (and in my installation at least it does append a newline at the end of the output, regardless of the input), but in any case we can take care of newlines just once at the end of the pipe: sh -c 'zenity --entry --title=unicodeit --text= | xargs -0 python3 -m unicodeit.cli | tr -d "\n" | xclip -sel clip'

Perfect!  Could you please add this last version to your answer?  That way, others won't have to read all the comments to learn the best solution.  And thanks a lot for your help.

@Algernon I've done it already, please note that this last version will strip any newline character from the output of unicodeit, as it's not a problem for the purpose of running a single LaTeX command; but if you wish to extend this to run multiple commands probably that should be taken care of. Let me know if this is ok, I can easily adjust that othwerise. You're welcome!

Thanks a lot!  I think it already handles longer LaTeX expressions as it should.  I would mainly use it for writing short latex snippets in emails or text files.  Finally, I have an efficient tool for this :-)

@Algernon I'm glad it helps! I'll still try to work out a solution to automate pasting to the active window, it itches a bit that it can't do this, it used to be so simple to do stuff like this with xdotool, I can't imagine there wouldn't be a way to do this on Wayland without being root. I'll ping you if I manage to fix that!
